# Cucumber Feature Files no longer highlighted brown if step definition not referenced

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, cucumber, cucumber-jvm, cucumber-java

I've updated my intelliJ to 2017.2.5 Community Edition (latest free version)

My Cucumber for Java and Gherkin addons are installed and enabled.

All of my tests still work, but for some reason, any new lines I add to a feature file, do not highlight brown anymore like they used to.  Nor do they give me the option to press ALT + ENTER to create the step definition

Has anyone else experienced this and if so, how did you resolve?

I checked the IntelliJ page here and they've no updates that this might currently be broken? - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/creating-step-definition.html

Thanks in advance
Dan

Comment: Please try File | Invalidate Caches | Invalidate and Restart. In case the problem persists, please report at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with the sample project attached.

Comment: Hi CrazyCoder  - I tried the Invalidate Caches and Restart, but the problem still persists.  I even tried to make a new feature file from scratch.  Intellij recognizes that it is a feature file but just doesn't highlight new lines as unreferenced step definitions.

Comment: Try with https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/.

Comment: Thank you - The latest 2017.3 public preview version fixes the issue.